# How to calculate the width of floated images in an article on a website?

Tags: html, image, layout, image-scaling

Currently I resize the images in articles using `style='width:...%'`, and it's pretty good if we're talking about common pagewidths (500-800px). But if we have an extra wide layout (it might be a fluid one), then this method isn't so good.

If we have an extra wide page, the images get bigger and need more vertical space, while the the text of the article consists of fewer lines so the text takes up less vertical space. This leads to an ugly layout of the article.

What method should I use to calculate the widths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the "max-width" and/or "max-height" css properties so the images are kept in reasonable size while keeping the ratio intact (setting both will NOT change the ratio). They are used like the "width" and "height" css styles.

Moreover, you can still set the width explicitly (in percentage or absolute) and the max-height/width will still take precedence if needed

Comment: Oh, what an elegant and easy solution :) I've been thinking of javascript calculations, but this is the best method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting only the width, increases or decreases the size of image in ratio (i.e. both height and width of the image increases in a ratio), so if you will explicitly mention the height in your css, then you would get the proper height (vertical space).

style="width:...%;height:...%"

Also, I agree with @idanzalz's answer - for different devices, where the layouts are different, use max-width and max-height css properties depending on device...